# From S3 to Kafka using Apache Camel Source

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-camel, apache-kafka-connect

I want to read data from amazon-s3 into kafka. I found camel-aws-s3-kafka-connector source and I try to use it and it works but... I want to read data from s3 without deleting files but execly once for each consumer without duplicates. It is possible to do this using only configuration file? I' ve already create file which looks like:

```
name=CamelSourceConnector
connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.awss3.CamelAwss3SourceConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.awss3.converters.S3ObjectConverter

camel.source.maxPollDuration=10000

topics=ReadTopic
#prefix=WriteTopic
camel.source.endpoint.prefix=full/path/to/WriteTopic2


camel.source.path.bucketNameOrArn=BucketName
camel.source.endpoint.autocloseBody=false

camel.source.endpoint.deleteAfterRead=false

camel.sink.endpoint.region=xxxx
camel.component.aws-s3.accessKey=xxxx
camel.component.aws-s3.secretKey=xxxx
```

<s>Additionaly with configuration as above I am not able to read only from "WriteTopic" but from all folders in s3, is it also possible to configure?
[S3Bucket folders with files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9X7o7.png)</s>

Comment: S3 doesn't have "folders". An S3 prefix of `WriteTopic/`will exclude `WriteTopic2/` data

Comment: My example is bad, even if I put in the prefix WriteTopic2 it also will read from both WriteTopic and WriteTopic2.

Comment: When I used camel.source.endpoint.prefix=full/path/to/WriteTopic2 instead of prefix=WriteTopic2 it works. :)

Comment: If that's the solution you're looking for, feel free to answer your own post below

Comment: It is a small part of solution what I am looking, it is more important for me to find answer at the top: "How to read data from s3 exacly one time per consumer without duplicates and without removing data in s3". Or In other words : "How to force Camel Source connector to read data once without removing."

Comment: Does `deleteAfterRead=false` not work? Regarding duplicates, I don't think you can prevent this without tracking which files have already been read (I'm not sure if this connector actually does that, you'd have to look at the source code, I think)

Comment: `deleteAfterRead=false` actually prevents data from being deleted. I m scared of that connector cannot prevent this without tracking which files have already been read. Do you know any other connectors which can do this?

Comment: Confluent has their own S3 Source that is used to read data written by their own S3 Sink. Otherwise, I'm not familiar with any other Kafka Connect S3 source, but that doesn't mean there aren't other options to read from S3+write to Kafka such as Flink, Spark, Nifi, etc., but they will all have the same "issue" of needing to actually track files if you needed to prevent reading anything more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround for duplicates problem, I'm not completly sure it is the best possible way but it may help somebody. My approach is described here: https://camel.apache.org/blog/2020/12/CKC-idempotency-070/ . I used camel.idempotency.repository.type=memory, and my configuration file looks like:

```
name=CamelAWS2S3SourceConnector connector.class=org.apache.camel.kafkaconnector.aws2s3.CamelAws2s3SourceConnector key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
camel.source.maxPollDuration=10000
topics=ReadTopic
# scieżka z ktorej czytamy dane
camel.source.endpoint.prefix=full/path/to/topic/prefix
camel.source.path.bucketNameOrArn="Bucket name"
camel.source.endpoint.deleteAfterRead=false
camel.component.aws2-s3.access-key=****
camel.component.aws2-s3.secret-key=****
camel.component.aws2-s3.region=****
#remove duplicates from messages# 
camel.idempotency.enabled=true 
camel.idempotency.repository.type=memory 
camel.idempotency.expression.type=body
```

It is also important that I changed camel connector library. Initially I used **camel-aws-s3-kafka-connector source**, to use Idempotent Consumer I need to change connector on **camel-aws2-s3-kafka-connector source**